# Escaped characters - \xFF

Tags: php

What do we call these strings and how they can be decoded? as I found these are `UTF-8` multi-byte characters and somewhere I noticed they are `UTF-32`

```
\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53
```

Comment: Out of any particular context it's just a sequence of bytes. You can treat it as whatever you want. PS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings#Eight-bit_environments

Comment: you need to ask a clear question then. What you asked looks like: I've found a `for` programming language construction. In some documents it's referred as a JS construction, in some - as C++

Comment: @zerkms my question has two sides and the second is how to decode them to ASCII or readable characters.

Comment: `$s = "\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53";

echo $s;` http://ideone.com/yLOMIA It's already ASCII

Comment: @zerkms what about `utf8_decode` funcction?

Comment: for what? Your string is **already** ASCII safe, so you can treat it as a single byte encoding string. If you wish - you can think it's UTF-8, but it wouldn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sequence of bytes `\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53` is an ASCII safe sequence. So you can either treat it as a single byte encoding string, or [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

```
$s = "\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53";

echo $s; // outputs LOBALS
```